# Female cat runs away thrice a week until I bring her back

Tags: cats

So, I have moved into a new house about 3 months ago. My female cat, I believe, was really stressed and ran out and did not come back for about 2 weeks or so. I later found out she was in one of the houses near ours which had a garage similar to our older place. Until one month ago, her behavior was normal as usual. But, again she goes to that house and pleads for help, so I bring her back. Then, again she runs away. What makes it worse is that her 8 months kitten too runs toward her mother. The last time, I brought her back, she had lost a lot of weight. I don't know if she's depressed or how I can help her. I'm really worried for my cats.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When moving house it is important to keep the cat inside for some time so the cat gets used to the new place.

When it is time to let the cat outside try to do this in the middle of the day and leave the door open. It is best if you are outside with your cat so the cat can see you. Only let the cat be outside for a short time.

Slowly increase the time your cat stays outside over several days so your cat gets used to the area.

There is a [similar question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10503/moving-cat-to-new-house-but-keeping-her-outdoors) to yours. The accepted answer is a really good one.